# Partition of unity in FEM with bubble functions

Tags: finite-element, navier-stokes, elasticity

In FEM with bubble functions, the field ($\boldsymbol{u}$) is approximated as a linear combination of the standard one ($\tilde{\boldsymbol{u}}$) plus the bubble field ($\boldsymbol{u}^b$). That is,
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{u} = \tilde{\boldsymbol{u}} + \boldsymbol{u}^b.
\end{equation}

Considering the addition of new basis functions and DOFs, I wonder about the partition of unity property.

Will it be violated? If yes, what are the potential consequences? If not, are the basis functions scaled accordingly?
Appreciate any insights and concerned references.

Comment: What is your definition of the partition of unity property? That the constant function $u(x) = 1$ is in the span of the basis functions? If so, then enriching a FE basis that already had the partition of 1 property with bubble functions doesn't violate it -- you can just take whatever basis coefficients give you back the constant function 1 and set all the bubble DoFs to 0.

Comment: Thank you @DanielShapero! I was referring to $\sum_i N_i=1$, $N_i$ as the basis functions. My confusion, which led to this question, was that the basis functions are used without scaling in many papers, leading to incorrect mass matrices. For example, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cma.2007.10.007

Comment: Gotcha, I understand now. I think the most important thing, for example to ensure global conservation, is to have that $1 \in \text{span}\{N_i\}$. (I'm mostly sure about this but I could be wrong.) The condition that $\sum_iN_i = 1$ is sufficient but not necessary to guarantee that $1 \in \text{span}\{N_i\}$ and indeed adding bubble functions, scaled or not, violates the one condition but not the other.

Comment: I think if the partition of unity is satisfied, then correct rigid body motion and mass conservation are ensured automatically.  If the basis functions are not scaled/modified appropriately, then the PU property is violated. While it might still capture the constant function as you mentioned, mass conservation is lost. I am surprised to see that many papers don't scale the basis functions correctly.

Comment: Can you explain how mass can be not conserved in Lagrangian (material) formulation? Paper referenced above is for such a case?

Comment: @likask, Violation of mass conservation is not from the formulation itself but due to the violation of partition of unity property of basis functions used. For example, for 3-noded tria, we have $N_1=\xi_3=1-\xi_1-\xi_2, N_2=\xi_1, N_3=\xi_2$ as the basis functions in local coordinates $(\xi_1, \xi_2)$. Once we add a cubic bubble $N_b=27 \xi_1 \xi_2 \xi_3$, $\sum N_i \neq 1$. The total mass will be higher than that of a triangle without the bubble function, resulting in violation of mass conservation.

Comment: To ensure mass conservation, we have to scale the basis function appropriately. The basis functions for P1+bubble would be: $N_1=\xi_3-9\xi_1\xi_2\xi_3, N_2=\xi_1-9\xi_1\xi_2\xi_3, N_3=\xi_2-9\xi_1\xi_2\xi_3, N_b=27\xi_1\xi_2\xi_3$.
In the referenced paper, the basis functions are used without scaling. See Eq. (39). Might not be realised it as only static cases were considered.

Comment: @ChennaK, I apologise, but I do not understand. In Lagrangian formulation, one needs to integrate over elements to calculate total mass. If integration is exact, masses in current and reference configurations should be the same, irrespective of used shape functions. It seems that you are concerned about how energy is distributed, i.e. kinetic energy, per DOFs, and its implications; for example, if bubble functions are present, what are the implications of lumping mass matrix and base functions scaling? However, this is a different story than the conservation of mass.

Comment: @likask. You are correct if we look at the mass conservation from the reference configuration to the current configuration. Exact integration of the element mass matrix should take care of this.
But look at it this way: mass conservation from the original element (without bubble functions) to an element with bubbles. If $\sum N_i \neq 1 (>1)$ with added bubble functions, then the total mass of the element would be higher than that of the element without bubbles, violating mass conservation. Check this paper for further details https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/epdf/10.1142/S021987621640003X

Comment: @ChennaK I do not have access to this paper; however, looking over some references, I see a discussion on the implication of using lumped matrix in the context of a portion of unity and enrichments, which I suggest above. Then some scaling is necessary. However, this issue is not present if you use a constant mass matrix. It would be interesting to see what is in referenced paper.

Comment: @likask, the issues due to the use of lumped mass matrix instead of the consistent mass matrix are different. This is a different problem altogether. To check the effect of not satisfying the partition of unity property, a quick test would be to calculate the total mass of the structure through element mass matrices. I will send you the paper.

Comment: @ChennaK I solved problems like this: https://cofea.readthedocs.io/en/latest/benchmarks/000-tuning-fork/results.html using base functions with various kinds of bubbles. If I used the same approximation order and used a consistent matrix between different tests, the type of bubble does not change of results, and the results would be correct for natural frequencies. BTW How do you calculate mass using a mass matrix? Do you mean summing contributions from each row? Lumping all elements together? You need PU to get the mass, but why do you need this property?